# Remounting imperfect RAID 6 after clean install

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, mdadm

I am running a small laboratory server (intermediate logins and data storage). It has 5 physical drives: one (sda) for `/`, and 4-drive RAID 6 (sd[b-e]) for `/home`. Due to a hardware fault, I had to replace the first drive.

Now, having reinstalled the system on a new drive, I wanted to remount the RAID and re-add the users. However, I've ran into a problem:

`mdadm --detail /dev/md/old_raid\:0` hints that sdb is not okay:

```
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Thu Oct 20 11:29:38 2016
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : 4294702080 (4095.75 GiB 4397.77 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 2147351040 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sat Sep 14 12:26:45 2019
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : Asna2:0
              UUID : 2cabe272:892c0ac8:9d5b8a30:75393439
            Events : 521636

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       4       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
       2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       3       8       65        3      active sync   /dev/sde1
```

However,
`mdadm --examine/dev/sdb1` lists this:

```
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 2cabe272:892c0ac8:9d5b8a30:75393439
           Name : Asna2:0
  Creation Time : Thu Oct 20 11:29:38 2016
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 4294703103 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
     Array Size : 4294702080 (4095.75 GiB 4397.77 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 4294702080 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=1023 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : a0aecf87:70ed61b2:3e36eb5c:8204d8f4

    Update Time : Wed Sep  4 00:39:22 2019
       Checksum : f0a3c084 - correct
         Events : 253375

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

And `mdadm --examine /dev/sdc` (apparently some bad blocks creeped in):

```
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 2cabe272:892c0ac8:9d5b8a30:75393439
           Name : Asna2:0
  Creation Time : Thu Oct 20 11:29:38 2016
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 5860271024 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 4294702080 (4095.75 GiB 4397.77 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 4294702080 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=1565568944 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : df8c2562:f7adc18e:6ae7246f:02ebe494

    Update Time : Sat Sep 14 12:26:45 2019
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : b70b8fa1 - correct
         Events : 521636

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

EDIT:
Printouts for sdd and sde are the same as for sdc, except for the bad block part.

Do I understand correctly that the best course of action is to

1) remove sdb and sdc

2) zero out sdb (or buy a second spare drive, those are 3Tb WD reds that are quite expensive)

3) cross fingers and rebuild the array

Or is there an alternative, less extreme solution?